# how to Change Attribute's parameter at runtime in Nunit

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, nunit, testcase

I want to change the assigned priority to test case at runtime

for ex:

```
[Test]
[Property("Priority", "change priority")]
public void TestCase1()
{
}

[Test]
[Property("Priority", "change priority")]
public void TestCase2()
{
}
```

so I want the value of priority which assigned to each test case to be dynamic and change based on specific condition

is it possible to make it dynamic

Comment: You can't change attributes at runtime, that's not what they are for. Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @DavidG
I want to categorize failed test cases to give them label with "High priority" after first run of run the category, as in Azure pipeline I need to run Failed test cases only

Comment: Why would you only re-run failed cases though?

Comment: @DavidG
There is no direct way in Azure to run only failed test cases, so I am trying to do a workaround to categorize failed test cases and make Azure run these test cases

Comment: Yes, but WHY would you only want to run failed tests? Just run them all.

Comment: As each category contains a lot of test cases and may be only 2 or 3 test cases failed from the category, so it's not a best practice to run all category again while we need to re-run only 2 or 3 test cases from the category (after the dev team fix failed test cases)

Note: the test case may take up to 10 mins in execution (desktop app)

Comment: Actually, it is best practice to run all tests. How do you know a code change didn't break something else?

Comment: Not all fix will be code fix, fix may be in configuration or environment issue or data issue so the fix of these issues will not affect any testcase except failed one, and any for code fix there will be another cycle which will run all of test cases

Comment: All of those can still cause tests to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. If you run all tests and then want to run those which failed, you have to get a list of the failed tests from TestResult.xml and set up your script to then run those tests. Since you don't say *how* you are running the tests in your pipeline, I can't tell you exactly how to do that, but for example, if you were using `nunit3-console.exe`, you might create a file containing the test names and use the `--testlist` option.

Whether or not it makes sense to rerun failed tests in your CI build is a different question but I tend to agree with @DavidG that it's a strange thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer it worked for me, 
I am using "Visual Studio Test" task in Azure pipeline so I don't know how to parse this command in the pipeline , (nunit3-console.exe .\MtTest.dll --testlist="failedtest.txt")
So do you have any idea how to make pipeline run  this command

Comment: Sorry, but you would need to provide a question with a lot more info in order to help with this problem, including why you want to run tests twice in the same pipeline. Don't put any new info in comments, however. Comments are often removed. Put info in this question or a new one so others in the future will see all the information.